# Java sharing an object between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, volatile

I have a database object which stores objects in various data structures. Several threads access this database, but the database is not always up to date. 
If I change the name of the object in one thread, the change is only reflected in the other threads if they have not accessed that object already.
If I add a new item in one thread, all threads are able to view this item.

I've tried declaring the database object as volatile, but the problem remains and I'm all out of ideas...

Thanks!

EDIT: Issue was traced down to not calling `.reset()` on my objectOutputStream

Comment: Is this *database object* handled manually as a cache? Is yes, it would be better to use a real cache library instead of writing yours from the ashes that already support multithreading. There are for example ehcache and infinispan.

Comment: This for a school project so we're not allowed to use any third party libraries. I'll give those a look though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to synchronize access to the database object instance.

In Java there are two two basic synchronization idioms:

- synchronized methods (apply the `synchronized` keyword to the methods accessing the database object instance)
- synchronized statements (wrap the code accessing the database object instance inside the `synchronized` block).

[More details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)

Comment: The threads are each constructed with the database as a parameter of the constructor, so I can't really synchronize access to the database instance, all the add and get methods of the database are synchronized though.

Comment: Appending the synchronized keyword to the get and add methods does not solve the issue. Because it prevents two (or more) threads from calling the add or get method at the same time, but does not prevent one thread from calling the get method and at the same another time calling the add method. In your case probably what has to be done is using the synchronized statement that will synchronize access to the data structure used to store the database data.

Comment: But if you want us to help you, you need to provide the code you are working on.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.
Even with only one thread accessing the database though, the changes are made to the database but the thread never sees them.

Comment: @user2352030 If all threads must take database object as parameters and you can't change implementation then only way out is create database object as singleton and pass that same database object instance while constructing all the threads...

Comment: @supernova This actually does not help, because there is actually one database object instance (singleton), which is accessed by numerous threads. If every thread had its own database object instance then there would be no synchronization issues.

Comment: @AdamSiemion I don't agree. The problem is if one thread update a value other thread should get it too. If all threads have different database object then they are not really sharing data but maintaining different copy. If we pass just one single object, then only sharing is possible. So when singleton is passed , it can only be accessed by one thread at a time , cuz now locking will be on intrinsic lock and all methods are synchronized on that.

Comment: @supernova Sorry do not understand what you do not agree to. Of course the SAME instance must be passed to all the threads. That is clear and does not need any discussion. My point was that your suggestion "create database object as singleton and pass that same database object instance while constructing all the threads" does not help any way because the problem is the synchronization of access from numerous threads to the SAME database object instance, not how to instantiate the database object.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. The same unique instance of the database object is of course being passed to every thread.
I've manged to narrow this down with a problem with my sockets - every thread that handles a connection is sending out the right information and getting updates, but the clients on the other side of the socket aren't receiving these.

Comment: Traced the issue down to not calling `.reset()` on my objectOutputStream

Answer (score 0):

well,you can copy the data is a new instance ,and OP on this instance 
like memcached cache design.
step: 
   1.get instance 
   2. copy instance 
   3. modify instance
   4.use